# cmake How to avoid system libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use a certain version of Qt4 in my project. I'm using debian and there is already an older version of Qt4 installed. When I'm using the find_package command in my CMakeLists file, of course, the system library is found, because the file /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake is used by cmake.

What I've done so far to link the newer Qt4, is to edit the paths with ccmake manually. The problem is I'm not allowed to install the newer Qt4 version in the directories of the system. Is there any easier solution to tell cmake don't use the system library just use another version. Of course I could create my own module and give the find_package command the path to my own module, but I think this is annoying and there have to be an more easier solution.

What I've also looked for, are there some environment variables which are used by the FindQt4.cmake module, but there aren't. - So, is there a general solution to avoid system libraries and to use libraries which installed in not system directories without doing some dirty tricks?

Comment: If I remember correctly, FindQt first searches for "qmake" in $PATH and determines the Qt install fomr the found qmake. Perhaps adding your own Qt install to $PATH would help?

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to use different versions of libraries on Linux is to use static linking. If you require the ability to use different versions of the same library simultaneously, you'll need to use an OS that supports that paradigm. Solaris (and its derivatives) is particularly good at that (compile with `-L` to point to the library to compile against and `-R` to indicate the path to that library at runtime). I believe BSD is the same.

Barring that, you'll want to create a `chroot` (a poor man's BSD jail) to deploy your application in. You'll install a copy of all the dependencies to the chroot, (use `ldd` to find them out) and the copy of Qt4 you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about system libraries in general. For Qt, you set the search path to qmake and qt will do the rest. Qmake path is set through QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE, I use Qt commercial and this is how I set the path in Cmake.

set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE $ENV{HOME}/QtCommercialSDK/Desktop/483/gcc-64/bin/qmake)